# Finding percentage values given min and max in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am very new to JavaScript and programming, so i hope you'll bear with me.
I am trying to write a program that places a pointer on a scale. The min and max values of the scale, as well as the values in between, changes depending on use. I am trying to define my minimum value as 0%, my max value as 100% and want to be able to place all other values in between.

```js
sortedResults = testResults.sort((a, b) => a - b);

SortedMin = sortedResults[0];
SortedMax = sortedResults[sortedResults.length - 1];

console.log(SortedMin);
console.log(SortedMax);
```

the values are taken from the sortedResults array and I am able to find the min and max, but simply cant figure out where to start.

Comment: what are some example values of `testResults`?

Comment: So you have to calculate your percentage of current value from MAX value

Comment: So you have to calculate value between min and max value?

Comment: The values in testResult varies from around 500 to around 3000. The length of the array also changes and is often from 2-15.

Comment: i have to calculate the percentage of all numbers in the sortedResults array, with the min. acting as 0% and the max. acting as 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a closure over `min` and `max` value and subtract `min` from `value` and `max` and get the percent value of both numbers.

```js
const
    getPercent = (min, max) => value => 100 * (value - min) / (max - min),
    testResults = [5, 2, 4, 3, 1],
    minVal = Math.min(...testResults),
    maxVal = Math.max(...testResults),
    sample = getPercent(minVal, maxVal);

console.log(testResults.map(sample));
```

Comment: i dont think i quite understand this structure. is the getPercente supposed to be a function?

Comment: yes, it is a function which returns another function for getting the percent value from a certain value.